# On Click Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, web, interactive

I would like to ask something about Jquery click function.The "Enterbutton" is a button can click to be function. But I failed. Is that I have missed something for the code?

[image: Whole interface for website]

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("Enterbutton").click(function(){   
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
```

I use Jquery to code for the interaction.

Comment: Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) You appear to have an invalid selector. Your syntax may also be invalid if this is all of your code. We also need to see the HTML you're working with. Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include it.

Comment: I don't think your selector is valid

Comment: You need to do some research concerning selectors.  $('Enterbutton') is looking for an element with a *tagname* of 'Enterbutton'.  You need to look up the element by either the actual tagname, id, class, or combination thereof.

Comment: Presumably you need `#Enterbutton` or `.Enterbutton`

Answer (score 0):

You need to revise selectors.

If you use `$('enterbutton')`, jQuery will look for this element:

```
<enterbutton>...</enterbutton>
```

If you use `$('#enterbutton')`, jQuery will look for this element:

```
<button id="enterbutton" type="button">...</button>
```

If you use `$('.enterbutton')`, jQuery will look for this element:

```
<button class="enterbutton" type="button">...</button>
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('enterbutton').click(function(){alert('The button with the type <enterbutton> was clicked.');});
$('#enterbutton').click(function(){alert('The button with id="enterbutton" was clicked.');});
$('.enterbutton').click(function(){alert('The button with class="enterbutton" was clicked.');});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<enterbutton type="button">Click Enterbutton</enterbutton>
<button id="enterbutton" type="button">Click #enterbutton</button>
<button class="enterbutton" type="button">Click .enterbutton</button>
```

**N.B.** *Obviously, **don't** use* `<enterbutton>...</enterbutton>` - it's invalid nonsense markup.

Comment: Happy to help, @yukikoying. Please accept the answer if it helped you to solve the problem. Thank you.